# Open NSWindowController ends with ARC semantic issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, automatic-ref-counting, nswindowcontroller

Working on a Mac 10.9 project with XCode, I left the mainWindow.xib with a button on it. When I click it, I want to open a new window which has its own .m/.h/.xib (called GenerateViewController).

In AppDelegate.h I added these lines :

```
#import "GenerateViewController.h"
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) GenerateViewController* generateViewController;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

And in AppDelegate.m I have :

```
- (IBAction)clickGenerateNewTable:(id)sender {
    self.generateViewController = [[GenerateViewController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"GenerateViewController"];
    [self.generateViewController showWindow:nil];
}
```

I have a ARC Semantic issue for the 2 last lines (starting with self.generateViewController) : **No visible @interface for 'GenerateViewController' declares the selector 'initWithWindowNibName:'**

Note : I looked into the similar questions, but all the answers differ and none worked for me (some are even outdated).

Comment: How is GenerateViewController declared?

Comment: All occurence of generateViewController in AppDelegate.h/.m is here. And nothing has been modified in GenerateViewController.h/.m (the basic XCode code when creating a ViewController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GenerateViewController tells from its name it is a view controller, so derived from **NSViewController**.
From the intent (open a new window), it should be derived from **NSWindowController** that provides the two methods ARC is telling are not found: *initWithWindowNibName:* and *showWindow:*

Comment: But is changing GenerateViewController into a NSWindowController a good practice ?

Comment: Not replacing, but for managing a window, the controller class should be derived from NSWindowController. Can you give more details about your Generate**View**Controller, and its associated XIB? I assume there is a Window object in the XIB.

Comment: Ok I got it now ! Actually I was too focus on ViewController instead of WindowController ! Thank you, you helped me a lot ! +1 (first time coding on Mac instead of iOS, the concept of windowControllers is new to me)